# How to optimise this SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

```
(@PaymentId int) 
returns int
as
begin
    Declare @viewedCount int

    Select @viewedCount = Count(OtSrno) 
    From OtTendersViewDetail 
    Where OTPaymentId = @PaymentId 
      And OTPaymentId is not null

    return (@viewedCount)
end
```

Comment: Optimize? Whats the bottleneck?

Comment: Add an index on OTPaymentId and count it instead of OtSrno

Comment: how to add index on OTPaymentId and count it instead of OtSrno

Comment: Voting to close, as there is no problem statement, no schema, no SQL Fiddle, no timing information, no desired optimisation requirements, and no evidence of prior effort. The tag spam is not great either - which of those versions of SQL Server _are_ you using?

Answer (score 0):

Optimize is normally somthing you do for complex operations - this one from pure SQL is as good as it gets.

What you can do is "with recompile" or "optimize for unknown" to avoid parameter sniffing - which means reusing query plans.

What you can also do (which is better) is check for OTPaymentId being null and if/else between 2 different select statements. Again, this is about query plan reuse / getting stuck with a bad query plan.